# Magento2 grid checkbox override old selected values

Tags: magento2

In Magento2, I have created a module for admin panel. There at Grid i select 2 rows and saved. It works fine.
But when i selected new row(It means 2 old and 1 new row) then it saved only new row rather than all 3 rows id.

My PrepareColumns for checkbox is

> protected function _prepareColumns()
>       {

```
    $this->addColumn(
        'in_products[]',
        [
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'html_name' => 'in_products',
            'required' =>  true,
            'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            'align' => 'center',
            'checked' => 'checked',
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
        ]
    );
```

Please help me where i made mistake.

Comment: Anyone is there to help me please.

Comment: No anybody is there ?